# Python list operations , Lambda Expression

Tags: python, lambda

```
def myFunction(name):
    index = 0
    list = self.getList()
    index = (x => x.name == name)
    return index
```

i want to use lamba expression to find an index of an element in a python list just as in C#. is it possible to use lambda expressions just as in C# to find an index of a  specific element in python list . If so please provide an example

Comment: Is your `list` a standard python list or an object?

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete example of what you want to do, with sample input and output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code is closer to what you are asking for:

```
def indexMatching(seq, condition):
    for i,x in enumerate(seq):
        if condition(x):
            return i
    return -1

class Z(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class X(object):
    def __init__(self, zs):
        self.mylist = list(zs)

    def indexByName(self, name):
        return indexMatching(self.mylist, lambda x: x.name==name)

x = X([Z('Fred'), Z('Barney'), Z('Wilma'), Z('Betty')])

print x.indexByName('Wilma')
```

Returns 2.

The key idea is to use enumerate to maintain an index value while iterating over the sequence. `enumerate(seq)` returns a series of (index,item) pairs. Then when you find a matching item, return the index.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use a lambda, the syntax is:

```
lambda param, list: return_value
```

For example, this is a lamdba that does addition:

```
lambda x, y: x + y
```

I'm not sure how this could make your function easier to write though, since this is the most obvious way:

```
def myFunction(name):
    for i, x in enumerate(self.getList()):
        if x.name == name:
            return i
```

Your lamdba would be this though:

```
lamdba x: x.name == name
```

So one horrible way of doing this is:

```
def myFunction(name):
    matches = [index
               for index, value in enumerate(self.getList())
               if value.name == name]
    if matches:
        return matches[0]
```

Comment: Not quite what the OP asked for, despite the checkmark.  Question didn't ask for match where the element in the list matched name, but where the element's name attribute (x.name) matches name.  Your lambda would be `lambda x: x.name == name`. And he doesn't want x, he wants the index of x in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do:

```
idx = [i for i, a in enumerate(lst) if a.name == name][0]
```

Comment: And there are no such element? It will throw index out of bound exception